# Why the curl return null？

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the yahoo woeid by php script.

I can access the url 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text="NewYork"&format=json' and get the json file in my browser.But when I use the curl it return null.

that's the code.

```
    public function getwoeid(){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text="'.$this->cityname.'"&format=json';
        //echo $url;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data=curl_exec($ch) or die($this->returnerror()); 
        curl_close($ch);
        $array = json_decode($data, true);
        return $array;
    }
```

when I try to access the 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text="上海"&format=json' the curl works fine.

I can't fix it.

any suggestion would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What's that ?? -> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_

Comment: $data=curl_exec($ch) or die($this->returnerror()); 
Die function will execute even if curl_exec return blank response so better use this, 
if($data === false)
{
  die($this->returnerror());
}

Comment: sorry I forget to delete the line. I should delete the line.I'm trying to modify the code.

Comment: What codepage U use? Utf-16?, Try urlencode your $url

Answer (score 3):

You can just use PHP's [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). The spaces must be encoded by [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php);

```
$url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text="'.$this->cityname.'"&format=json';
$data = file_get_contents(urlencode($url));
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got answer from your code:

> string 'HTTP Version Not Supported
>
> �' (length=210)

The PlaceFinder Web service supports only the HTTP GET method. Other HTTP methods are not supported.

You cannot use CURL,because curl works as a POST method.
Please read here: http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/requests.html

Comment: actualy you can use cURL to make GET requests.

Comment: Yes,you are right,by default it's a post method.Better to use file_get_contents() for it.

Comment: but why I can get the json by curl for this url  'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text="Shanghai"&format=json'

Comment: @joe u can,u should use GET metod instead of post.

Comment: I've fix it.actually I don't know the reason! 

public function getwoeid(){
  $defaults = array( 
         CURLOPT_URL => 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?'. http_build_query(array('q'=>'select * from geo.places where text="'.$this->cityname.'"','format'=>'json')), 
         CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, 
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE 
     ); 
     $ch = curl_init(); 
     curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults); 
     if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) 
     { 
         $this->returnerror();
      } 
     curl_close($ch); 
  $array = json_decode($result, true);
  return $array;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You have an open curl_setopt(). it is below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ <------
```

Comment: I forget to delete the line.it should be deleted.